# Can't get "likes" our of Facebook JSON data using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to display the # of "likes" of a user selected entity that has a facebook site.  The url that's passed in is the entities facebook name:

```
public int GetLikes(string url)
    {
        string jsonString = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=" + url);
        Dictionary<string, dynamic> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(jsonString);
        int keyValues = values.Count;
        int likes = values["likes"];
        return likes;
     }
```

I get an error that "likes" is not found in the value.  But it's clearly there.  Below is a sample of the JSON data that's returned from facebook:

```
{
"disney": {
  "about": "\"It's kind of fun to do the impossible.\" - Walt Disney",
  "category": "Company",
  "checkins": 26,
  "description": "This Page is a place for our Fans.  However, we do need to have certain rules.  Please be aware that we do not accept or consider unsolicited idea submissions and, also, we must reserve the right to remove any posting or other material that we find off-topic, inappropriate or objectionable.",
  "founded": "1923",
  "is_published": true,
  "talking_about_count": 543991,
  "username": "Disney",
  "website": "http://disney.com",
  "were_here_count": 0,
  "id": "11784025953",
  "name": "Disney",
  "link": "http://www.facebook.com/Disney",
  "likes": 46622418,
  "cover": {
     "cover_id": "10152010506970954",
     "source": "http://sphotos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/t1.0-9/s720x720/1960125_10152010506970954_1312297640_n.png",
     "offset_y": 0,
     "offset_x": 0
  }
  }
  }
```

I have tried many different things.  Getting and deserializing the JSON data isn't a problem but I haven't been able to find a way to get any of the elements.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Create a class that mimics your JSON string (object) structure:

```
public class JSONobject
{        
    public Disney = new Disney();
}

public class Disney
{
    public string about { get; set; }
    public string category{get;set;}
    public int checkins = {get;set;}
    ........

    public int likes = {get;set;}

    ........
    public Cover = new Cover();
}

public class Cover
{
    public int cover_id { get;set; }
    ........
}
```

Then, initialize the object as well as the serializer:

```
JSONobject jsonOb = new JSONobject();

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
```

Finally, parse the jsonString into your defined class:

```
try
{    
    jsonOb = serializer.Deserialize<JSONobject>(jsonString);

    //ViewBag.jsondecoded = "Yes";
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //ViewBag.jsonDecoded = "No" + ", Exception: " + e.Message.ToString();
}
```

Retrieving variables:

```
string about = jsonOb.Disney.about;
string category = jsonOb.Disney.category;
int checkins = jsonOb.Disney.checkins;
int likes    = jsonOb.Disney.likes;
Cover cover  = jsonOb.Disney.Cover;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I ended up going a different route because I didn't want to create a class that mimics the JSON since I'm only interested in one data point and the class name will change depending on what url is passed to the method.  I used:               'string jsonString = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=" + url);
                dynamic dyn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
                dynamic json = dyn[url];                
                int likes = (int)json["likes"];    
                return likes;'

Comment: No problem, I was actually going to add, the serializer does not expect a perfect match. So it will work as well if you only declare what you are interested in. Such as Disney>Likes. This way you only get int likes. Glad you worked it out.